# SQL Server - Shrink DB still large file tempdb_mssql_2

Tags: sql-server, shrink, tempdb

I have a server that is getting full, due to some temp table processing.

We found that our tempdb file was at 33.8 GB
and there was a another file at 33.8 GB called `tempdb_mssql_2`

Now then, we ran the following:

```sql
USE [tempdb]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'templog' , 0)
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'tempdev' , 0)
GO
```

The tempdb did shrink as expected, but the other file `tempdb_mssql_2` is still 33.8 GB
I believe this file is a secondary data file created by SQL, but don't know how to clear it down.

we tried this:

```sql
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'tempdb_mssql_2' ,0)
GO
```

But this gave us this error:

> Msg 8985, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
> Could not locate file 'tempdb_mssql_2' for database 'tempdb' in sys.database_files. The file either does not exist, or was dropped.

Comment: You just shrank the one (data) file >_< Now the files are different sizes which will *ruin* the benefit of having multiple database files...

Comment: In truth, this was a *bad* decision. 70GB~ is pretty small in modern systems, and shrinking `tempdb` is probably *never* a good decision (if you *really* needed it smaller, then restarting the instance would probably be a better idea). Honestly, if you *can* I would check that the shrink didn't mangle the initial sizes of your databases, if it did fix that, and then consider restarting the instance just os SQL Server can rebuild tempdb. Then look for reclaiming space a *different* way.

Comment: You *shouldn't* be shrinking `tempdb` to *start* with.

Comment: We had space run out on the server, rebooting wasn't an option (don't ask, not my server setup), I needed to cleardown the temp file due to someone running a seriously over engineered report query. 
The goal was to snap it down, and then let it grow again when done. 
So my original question, HOW do I shrink tempdb_mssql_2, even if you feel it's a bad idea. :)

Comment: Replace `tempdev` with the correct name of the file; `SHRINKFILE` as it's name suggests *shrinks* a *file*. You have 2 files, so you need to shrink *both* files. But, again, this is a **bad** idea. You are very likely going to cause *more* problems going down this path.

Comment: *"We had space run out on the server"* Freeing up ~60GB is just kicking the can down the street, if I am honest. Like I said before, this is not only a *bad* solution, it's the *wrong* solution. If you are low on space then you should really be considering the purchase of more, or working out where you can free space in *different* ways.

Comment: Instead of shrinking individual files, you can shrink all the files for the database with the command dbcc shrinkdatabase ('TempDB')

Comment: If you need to get names of your other files, use `SELECT name
FROM tempdb.sys.database_files
WHERE name NOT IN ('templog','tempdev');` I suspect your other file is called `tempdev2`

Comment: @ThomA
Thank you, you're advice helped me solve the issue temporarily but as you say, it's not the final solution. Not my server setup as I said, and that is going to change soon.

Comment: Move that sucker to the cloud. As an EC2 instance in AWS, for example, it's trivial to expand an EBS volume and then extend the NTFS partition within it, all while leaving the server online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to put an answer here for anyone else that stumbles across this:

1. Shrink DB is a bad idea, it's better to increase resources.
2. If you still need to shrink all the tempdbs then you can do so by first finding the them with the following script:

`SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.database_files WHERE name NOT IN ('templog','tempdev');`

In my case this returned a single file called `temp2`

From that you will get the name of the tempDB's and can shrink them

```sql
USE [tempdb]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'temp2' , 0)
GO
```